# Why does clearinterval change thing in this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

```
var interval = setInterval(function (){
    console.log("Hello world");
}, 1000);

var thing = interval;
console.log(thing);
clearInterval(interval);
console.log("interval cleared");
console.log(thing);
```

`thing` is printed differently before and after clearing `interval` and I can't understand why. Halp pls?

**Edit:** Sorry, I should've been clearer. I'm using node.js, and this is the output to the above code:

```
{ _idleTimeout: 1000,
  _idlePrev: 
   { _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     msecs: 1000,
     ontimeout: [Function: listOnTimeout] },
  _idleNext: 
   { _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     msecs: 1000,
     ontimeout: [Function: listOnTimeout] },
  _idleStart: 1394616963526,
  _onTimeout: [Function: wrapper],
  _repeat: true }
interval cleared
{ _idleTimeout: -1,
  _idlePrev: null,
  _idleNext: null,
  _idleStart: 1394616963526,
  _onTimeout: null,
  _repeat: false,
  ontimeout: null }
```

Why is `thing` affected by the clearInterval at all?

Comment: It prints `1` both times for me.

Comment: What is different about the way it's printed?

Comment: I should probably note that I'm using node.js. Basically, you'd think that `thing would be unchanged` but actually clearInterval clears thing as well as interval when I only want it to clear interval. So before, it prints the interval in its running/pre-running state and the print after it prints it after it's been cleared when it hasn't, only interval has been cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two variables `interval` and `thing` both refer to the same `Timer` object. When you call `clearInterval`, it modifies that object, and this is what `console.log` shows.

It's similar to the following code:

```
var obj1 = { a : 3 };
var obj2 = obj1;
obj1.a = 4;
console.log(obj2);
```

This will log `{ a : 4 }`. If you want the two variables to refer to different objects, you need to clone the object; see

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object/122704#122704)

Comment: Right, ok. So how in your example, how would I make obj2 a new instance of obj1?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object/122704#122704

Answer (score 1):

`clearInterval(interval);` is used to cancel the  repeated action which was set up by `setInterval`.

But in your code, `thing` is assigned before `clearInterval(interval);`, so it will **not** printed differently.

***Update:***

Things are different in `node.js`, in nodejs, `setInterval` returns an Timer object but not a number.
So clear `interval` will clear `thing` too, because they refer to same object.

Comment: He says it _is_ printed differently. It's not an answer to say that it won't be.